# PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions in one

Tags: php

How to How to check PHP multiple Conditional Statements in one. 
Somethig like this :

```
if($image_ex == "{gif|jpg|png|jpeg}"){
     //something
}
```

Comment: use logical operators

Comment: Use || logical operator.

Comment: Also, watch for typo ? `"{gif|jpg|png|jpeg}")`

Comment: I know that but i need something like that.

Comment: Technically the answer to your question is you can use logical operators to place many conditions inside an if-statement. Although a better approach would be to use a regular expression  with `preg_match` or an array as in @chris85's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a regex, use multiple conditions, or put the values in an array. I'd use http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

```
if (in_array($image_ex , array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'))) {
```

A regex approach could be:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:gif|png|jpe?g)$/', $image_ex)){
```

or the long multiple conditions approach:

```
if($image_ex == "gif" || $image_ex == "jpg" || etc..){
```

Comment: I didn't think of `in_array()`